# Border is applied to siblings when it shouldn't be

Tags: html, css, border, erb

I'm having what would seem a very basic css problem that shouldn't be an issue.  I have three divs:
(Output directly from firebug.  Each div contains a lot of content and nested form partials (rails) so below is an abbreviation)

```
<div class="dynamic-container person">
    <div class="symegrid"></div>
    <div class="officer tf-attribute"></div>
    <div class="director tf-attribute"></div>
</div>
```

Divs with class `tf-attribute` should have a boarder:

```
div.tf-attribute{
    border: medium solid #a5ac20;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Strange thing is that the border is being applied to the div of class `symegrid`.  When I use firebug to inspect the computed attributes of the `symegrid` div, no border is listed.  If I take the border off of `tf-attribute`, the one arround `symegrid` disappears.

I doubt anyone would be able to give me a difinitive answer on this but I'm running out of ideas.  Has anyone seen this sort of behavior before?  Any ideas/thoughts would be appreciated.

**In response to comments I've gotten:**

*It's been quite fairly suggested that I post a reproduction of the problem in a fiddle or something like that.* I'm currently trying to reproduce this in a fiddle but can't so far.  Will post it if I'm able to do so (though I suspect reproducing it would likely give me the info I need to solve the problem)

Comment: [Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (link)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see the issue

Comment: The code that you have posted is invalid. Please post the correct code snippet so that we can help. divs need to be closed.

Comment: A [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) would be very helpful on this one.

Comment: @SexyTurnip Very fair point.  I'm actually trying to reproduce the issue in a fiddle and so far I can't :-P  Will post if I figure it out.

Comment: @ThilakRao The html above is an abbreviation provided by firebug  There are a lot of nested divs within each listed.  All have matching `</div>` closures.  I'll close up the divs above to avoid confusion.

Comment: _"I suspect reproducing it would likely give me the info I need to solve the problem"_ - that's usually the case

Comment: check if you don't have `border:inherit` somewhere... or things like that. he can be getting it from a parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for some reason the `div.officer.tf-attribute` happened to be sizing itself to include the exact boundaries of `div.symegrid`, leaving its own contents below.  Therefore `div.symegrid` only appeared to have a border and because the content of `div.officer.tf-attribute` was sandwitched between two bordered divs, it appeared to have a border itself.  (Still can't get it to do that in a fiddle but whatever)

Anyway, all I needed was to add

```
div.tf-attribute{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And it was all better. :-P  Thanks to everyone who was so kind to spend their time on this nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

You having missing closing `div tag`

See the fiddle: "https://jsfiddle.net/s48o7kr1/"

The code becomes:

```
<div class="dynamic-container person">
    <div class="symegrid"></div>
    <div class="officer tf-attribute"></div>
    <div class="director tf-attribute"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: even if you don't close the tags you won't have 3 borders. the issue is probably another thing.

Comment: All divs are closed.  The above html is a firebug abbreviation.  I'll close them up to avoid confusion.

Comment: I tired the html in fiddle it is working fine that is why I thought it is the issue

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to

```
<div class="dynamic-container person">
    <div class="symegrid"></div>
    <div class="officer tf-attribute"></div>
    <div class="director tf-attribute"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: All divs are closed properly.  I edited the code above to clarify.  Also, `div.symegrid` is a sibling of `div.tf-attribute`.